# Fetch vs FetchAll with mysql_query | PHP

Tags: php, fetch, php-5.4

I am aware that using `mysql_query` is terrible and the much better / preferred way of doing this is like so:

**PREFERRED**

```
$dbquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

**BUT I HAVE TO**

However, working with a legacy system that uses `mysql_query` ... running into a `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted` error when calling `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

**QUESTION**

Does `msyql_query` / `mysql_fetch_` have functionality that acts as `fetch` vs `fetchAll`?

Comment: I understand you are working with a legacy system, but why continue to write outdated code? What is stopping you from properly writing the new code you are working on?

Comment: I don't think your issue is from using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, the result from the query is exhausting your max allowed memory size.

Comment: The memory limit is because you are returning to much data, right? Fetchall would still have that issue. Are you selecting with `*` whereas you could just list some of the columns? Are you needing all data at once? Maybe paginate the results?

Comment: Is there raw image data in there or something?  That's an awful lot for one row.  Alternatively, are you running this within a loop and appending the results into an array each time through?

Comment: @user3783243 `fetchall()` would still have that issue, but `fetch()` would not. I am not selecting with `*`. I am not sure how I would paginate the results as there is not an auto incremented primary key.

Comment: For pagination, you can use the ```LIMIT [start row],[num_rows]``` clause in your query.

Comment: @TT4M.C `fetch()` also would if you did `while($row = fetch..){ $something[] = $row;}` because you'd be building an array of all results still. Maybe provide your actual code and give us an idea about what you are selecting. Without that we're all guessing

Comment: @SloanThrasher That is how I am doing it, if you want to make an answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Use a loop in PHP and read one row at a time. *(not needed if you use #2)*
2. Use the `LIMIT {start row},{number of rows}` clause in your SQL statement for pagination.